# Automapper - Conditional mapping for both IQueryable extensions and in-memory

Tags: c#, automapper, automapper-6

I have classes EntityA to DtoA and 2 usages of automapper in my .NET project.

First one is:

```
var result1 = dbContext
    .Set<EntityA>()
    .Where(...)
    .ProjectTo<DtoA>(new { param1 = true } )
    .ToList();
```

And the second:

```
var aList = dbContext
    .Set<EntityA>()
    .Where(...)
    .ToList();

var result = Mapper
    .Map<DtoA[]>(aList, options => options.Items["param1"] = true);
```

I want to have a reusable mapping working for both cases. This mapping has to be conditional for some fields based on param1 value.
How to implement it within single **CreateMap<,>().ForMember()** API ?

Comment: The only way it would work is to have the parameter in the source object instead.

Comment: @LucianBargaoanu and what to do with this parameter?

Comment: Instead of checking a parameter you would have to check a property in the source object.

Comment: @LucianBargaoanu and what to write in .ForMember statement then? Something like MapFrom with ternary operator?

Comment: Yes, whatever would work for both cases. Start with ProjectTo.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't exactly get the logic you want, but you could put any logic into a method like this:

```
 c.CreateMap<A, B>()
    .ForMember(dest => dest.Items, opt => opt.ResolveUsing(src =>
    {
       if (src.Items["param1"] == true)
       {
           // Do whatever
       }

       return /*do whatever else*/;
    }));
```

Is that what you want or did I misunderstand the question?

**Edit:**
I'll give it another try:

```
var result1 = dbContext
    .Set<EntityA>()
    .Where(...)
    .Select(c => mapper.Map<A>(c))
    .ToList();
```

However still not understanding completely what you want. Can you give an example with data, like which set should be converted into which?

Comment: yeah, you got the idea.
But the pitfall here is that opt.ResolveUsing does not work for .ProjectTo<>() API.
The documentation offers to use *parameterization* approach with .MapFrom API http://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Queryable-Extensions.html#parameterization here.

The question is how to make both parameterization approaches work withing single mapping ? Or, maybe, how to split support both .MapFrom and .ProjectTo for EntityA->DtoA in a single application ?